# How do I get the new version of Windows 10's on-screen keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard, touch-keyboard

My Surface Pro computer is running Windows Version 10.0.22000 Build 22000, the onscreen keyboard looks like this:

[image]

On my desktop Windows 10 computer (running Windows version 10.0.19044 Build 19044), the keyboard looks like this:

[image]

It lacks the "docking" option which makes itself dock to the current foreground window.

Is there a way to get the other / newer on-screen keyboard on my desktop computer, too?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two "on screen keyboards".

The one you are looking for is called "touch keyboard" `tabtip.exe`, usually you access it via the icon on the taskbar notification area. You need to enable the icon via right click on the taskbar:

[image]

The other one is the "on-screen keyboard" `osk.exe` the one you are opening right now.